# Images not showing up in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a view with a table containing list of charges. I show a check mark image as one of the column. It is defined as input type as checkbox. The user can check/uncheck by clicking the column. he check mark image does not show up in IE8 at all. Following is the relevant inline css/script in the view (.cshtml).

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label
        {
            padding-left: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 25px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0 0;
            font-size: 15px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

         input[type=text].css-text
    {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        margin: -1px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }
        input[type=text].css-text + label.css-textlabel
        {
            padding-left: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 25px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0 0;
            font-size: 15px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-image: url(../images/checkmark.png);
        }


        input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label
        {
            background-image: url(../images/check-mark-sm.png);
        }

         input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox.checked + label.css-label
        {
             background-image: url(../images/check-mark-sm.png);
        }

    .css-label
    {
          background-image: url(../images/checknomark.png);

   }
```

The table in the view is loaded by reading the model in the view. Following is the code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.OpenCharges.Count; i++)
{
var style = (i + 1) % 2 != 0 ? "background1" : "background2";
var status = @Model.OpenCharges[i].Status;
var disabled = status != "Open" ? "disabled" : "checked=\"checked\" ";
<td style="padding: 5px;" class="body @style">
<input id="OpenCharges-Checkbox-@i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="@Model.OpenCharges[i].AmountRemaining" IdForRecord="@Model.OpenCharges[i].Id" @disabled  />
<label for="OpenCharges-Checkbox-@i" class="css-label"></label>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
}
```

For some reason, the check mark is not visible in IE8. I have spent long hours and nothing works for me. The same code works on all other browsers and versions of IE >8. Any ideas what I need to do?
**Following things were attempted before posting this question:**

1. Changed **background-image:url** to **background:transparent url()**
2. Used `<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script> <![endif]-->`

Comment: I'm guessing it's an element without content ?

Comment: @adeneo - Didnt get your question? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: IE is sensitive about syntax so few suggestion try to give "" code on image path or try full path instead of relative and make sure there is proper spacing.